# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in POST data to Mysql using NodeJs and ReactJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am working on ReactJs and NodeJS in sending data to MySql, in my frontPage.js The problem is I already tested the API to post data using Postman and no error appears. And the problem comes when I tried in ReactJs, I coded this :

```
class InputEndUser extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            project_type: '',
            status : '',
            subject : '',
            enduser_name : '',
            location : '',
            cp_1 : '',
            cp1_hp : '',
            cp1_jpos: '',
            cp_2 : '',
            cp2_hp : '',
            cp2_jpos : '',
            quot_num : '',
            quot_date : '',
            note : ''

        }
        this.handleProject_type = this.handleProject_type.bind(this);
        this.handleStatus = this.handleStatus.bind(this);
        this.handleSubject = this.handleSubject.bind(this);
        this.handleEnduser_name = this.handleEnduser_name.bind(this);
        this.handleLocation = this.handleLocation.bind(this);
        this.handleCP1 = this.handleCP1.bind(this);
        this.handleCP1_hp = this.handleCP1_hp.bind(this);
        this.handleCP1_jpos = this.handleCP1_jpos.bind(this);
        this.handleCP2 = this.handleCP2.bind(this);
        this.handleCP2 = this.handleCP2.bind(this);
        this.handleCP2_hp = this.handleCP2_hp.bind(this);
        this.handleCP2_jpos = this.handleCP2_jpos.bind(this);
        this.handleQuot_num = this.handleQuot_num.bind(this);
        this.handleQuot_date = this.handleQuot_date.bind (this);
        this.handleNotes = this.handleNotes.bind(this);
    }

    handleProject_type(event){
        this.setState ({
            project_type : event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleStatus(event){
        this.setState({
            status: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubject(event){
        this.setState({
            subject: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleEnduser_name (event) {
        this.setState({
            enduser_name: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleLocation(event){
        this.setState({
            location: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleCP1(event){
        this.setState({
            cp_1: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleCP1_hp(event){
        this.setState ({
            cp1_hp : event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleCP1_jpos(event){
        this.setState ({
            cp1_jpos : event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleCP2(event){
        this.setState({
            cp_2: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleCP2_hp(event){
        this.setState ({
            cp2_hp : event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleCP2_jpos(event){
        this.setState ({
            cp2_jpos : event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleQuot_num(event) {
        this.setState ({
            quot_num : event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleQuot_date (event) {
        this.setState({
            quot_date : event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleNotes(event) {
        this.setState({
            note : event.target.value
        })
    }

    submitEndUser(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/enduser', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then ((response) => {
            return response.json;
        })
        .then ((body) => {
            console.log(body);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

and My API in server.js :

```
app.post('/enduser', (req, res) => {
  let POST_ENDUSER_QUERY =  {
    project_id: req.body.project_id,
    project_type: req.body.project_type,
    status: req.body.status,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    endUser_name: req.body.endUser_name,
    location: req.body.location,
    cp_1: req.body.cp_1,
    cp1_hp: req.body.cp1_hp,
    cp1_jpos: req.body.cp1_jpos,
    cp_2: req.body.cp_1,
    cp2_hp: req.body.cp1_hp,
    cp2_jpos: req.body.cp1_jpos,
    quot_num: req.body.quot_num,
    quot_date: req.body.quot_date,
    note: req.body.note,
    image: req.body.image,
    estimated_value: req.body.estimated_value
  };
  if (!POST_ENDUSER_QUERY) {
    return res.status(400).send({ err: true, message: 'Please project name' });
  }

  let query = `INSERT INTO enduser_tbl (project_id, project_type, status, subject, endUser_name, location, cp_1, cp1_hp, cp1_jpos, cp_2, cp2_hp, cp2_jpos, quot_num,quot_date, note, image, estimated_value) VALUES (
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.project_id}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.project_type}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.status}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.subject}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.endUser_name}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.location}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp_1}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp1_hp}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp1_jpos}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp_2}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp2_hp}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp2_jpos}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.quot_num}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.quot_date}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.note}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.image}',
    '${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.estimated_value}'
    )`;
  dbConn.query(query, ( err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    return res.status(200).json({"status": 200, "err" : null, "data": results});
  });
});
```

and the error came : 
[image]

also in terminal when I test it with some kind of data, appears like this:
[image]

Comment: Please read the sqlMessage, you can already see there the root cause.

Comment: It means the question is irrelevant. You are right!

Comment: @user207421 that's the problem confused me, I tried using postman to test POST API, there is no error both in sql and connection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up a bodyparser in your NodeJS API ?  I know that with express and koa you have to install a module to retrieve the contents of the body and store it in `req.body` or `ctx.request.body`.

For [express](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

For [koa](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser)

Comment: My bad, I found the issue, please look at my other reply : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60296951/9681418

Comment: thats the error http://localhost:4000/enduser net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Don't bother with this message on the front-end side in the case of an API connection, first study the errors found on the back-end side, i.e. the fact that the values of `req.body`are `undefined` look at my other answer and tell me if it worked.

Comment: adding the body data is still not working, I still got error in trying fetch data, using postman to test the API, I got this
{
    "status": 200,
    "err": null,
    "data": {
        "fieldCount": 0,
        "affectedRows": 1,
        "insertId": 15,
        "serverStatus": 2,
        "warningCount": 0,
        "message": "",
        "protocol41": true,
        "changedRows": 0
    }
}

Comment: After adding the body data what is back-end error message now ?

Comment: I got this now 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ...
but in Inspect browser, I can see the data appears

Comment: I am asking for the back-end aka NodeJS log error not the reactJS log.

Comment: sorry ...
in terminal I got this code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1366,
  sqlMessage: "Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'project_id' at row 1",

Comment: Ok it's normal you never set or send a `project_id` property/value in your React project, now you can debug alone by `console.log` the `this.state` on react on your front and the `POST_ENDUSER_QUERY` on your backend and you will see the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add body data to your POST in React :

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/enduser', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
```

Try to change it to :

```
 fetch('http://localhost:4000/enduser', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem for my case here ...
after trying with some suggestions...

I needed to include body in my POST like this :

```
 fetch('http://localhost:4000/enduser', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        })
```

Finally I solved the problem in back-end connection with Auto Increment field in mysql database. I change project_id in values with this :

```
 let query = `INSERT INTO enduser_tbl (project_id, project_type, status, subject, endUser_name, location, cp_1, cp1_hp, cp1_jpos, cp_2, cp2_hp, cp2_jpos, quot_num,quot_date, note, image, estimated_value) VALUES (
0,
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.project_type}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.status}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.subject}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.endUser_name}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.location}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp_1}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp1_hp}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp1_jpos}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp_2}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp2_hp}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.cp2_jpos}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.quot_num}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.quot_date}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.note}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.image}',
'${POST_ENDUSER_QUERY.estimated_value}'
)`;
```

and it's work and I already tested in Postman

Answer (score -2):

Please setup CORS in order to make your Api's work

Comment: I already setup CORS in server.js ... do I need to set it also in the browser?

Comment: have you given the origin to it? Also can you show me the errors in your console?

Comment: app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  next();
});

I already put it all ... and I think this is not the problem appears with CORS